# Equations reducible to Bessel's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, bessel-functions

I am solving a differential equation:
$$
xy'' + ay' + k^{2}xy = 0,
\tag{1}
$$
where $a$ and $k$ are some constants, one way to solve this equation is to reduce it to Bessel's form:
$$
x^{2}y'' + xy' + (k^{2}x^{2} - n^{2})y = 0,
\tag{2}
$$
Since a solution is known for Bessel's equation depending upon the nature of $n$. The standard way to reduce $(1)$ to $(2)$ is to make the substitution $$y = x^{n}z,$$where $z = z(x)$. **I am interested in knowing how one arrives or how one knows to do that specific substitution** to reduce $(1)$ to $(2)$. Can anybody enlighten me or lead me to a source?

Comment: Can't you make the substitution $y=x^n z$ ?

Comment: Mahesh, there is no better answer other than "you just see it". It comes with experience and practice.

Comment: Frank Bowman's book on Bessel Functions has a section dedicated to transformations of Bessel's equation which explores a slightly more general transformation than the one you state.  Check out page 117 of this pdf - it was helpful for me when I had a similar question: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Vikash-Pandey-7/post/Can-anyone-suggest-books-on-the-fundamental-understanding-of-bessel-functions-with-worked-examples/attachment/59d61e2079197b807797c85a/AS%3A276097904410638%401442838278612/download/Bowman_Bessel_Functions.pdf